# KL-divergence from t-SNE embedding

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How can I get the final KL-divergence among probability distributions after t-SNE embedding? I am using the TSNE function from the sklearn.manifold package. Is there any parameter that I can access for that?

Answer (score 4):

The fit model has an attribute called kl_divergence_.(see [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html)).

Answer (score 2):

A trick you could use is to set the parameter "verbose" of the TSNE function. With verbose=2, you would get the following output:

```
[t-SNE] Computing pairwise distances...
[t-SNE] Computing 91 nearest neighbors...
[t-SNE] Computed conditional probabilities for sample 1000 / 1262
[t-SNE] Computed conditional probabilities for sample 1262 / 1262
[t-SNE] Mean sigma: 0.000000
[t-SNE] Iteration 25: error = 0.8776680, gradient norm = 0.0074852
[t-SNE] Iteration 50: error = 0.6590481, gradient norm = 0.0073444
[t-SNE] Iteration 75: error = 0.2875383, gradient norm = 0.0039135
[t-SNE] Iteration 100: error = 0.2597728, gradient norm = 0.0032396
[t-SNE] Error after 100 iterations with early exaggeration: 0.259773
[t-SNE] Iteration 125: error = 0.2333734, gradient norm = 0.0030973
[t-SNE] Iteration 150: error = 0.2164318, gradient norm = 0.0045540
[t-SNE] Iteration 175: error = 0.2175926, gradient norm = 0.0035685
[t-SNE] Iteration 200: error = 0.2102150, gradient norm = 0.0041453
[t-SNE] Iteration 225: error = 0.2186255, gradient norm = 0.0040576
[t-SNE] Iteration 250: error = 0.2160356, gradient norm = 0.0036579
[t-SNE] Iteration 250: did not make any progress during the last 30 episodes. Finished.
[t-SNE] Error after 250 iterations: 0.216036
```

although you don't have the value of KL stored as a variable, you can compare different solutions and pick the one with the lowest KL.